# How do I resolve a Syntax error in the INSERT INTO Access Database statement?

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I have an initial `UserForm` that prompts the user for his/her login credentials and checks them against an Access Database (.mdb). As you'd imagine, if the credentials don't match, it won't allow them to login, if they do, it logs in.

After this, a "Home" `UserForm` displays (which I only have the `AddUser` button on it, and an empty `Settings` button). Once the user clicks on ["Add User..."], the `AddUserForm` displays. In this there are textboxes for Username (`UsernameTextbox`), Password (`PasswordTextbox`), First Name (`FirstNameTextbox`), Last Name (`LastNameTextbox`), Department (`DepartmentList`),  and Position  (`PositionList`). (Refer to picture)

While testing the "INSERT INTO" command text for my OleDbCommand, I used only the FirstName and LastName `TextBoxes`, which successfully added the `FirstNameTextbox.Text` to the FirstName column and the `LastNameTextbox.Text` to the LastName column within the Database.

Once I added the remaining criterion, however, I've gotten this error message stating there's a Syntax error in the INSERT INTO statement, but I'm unsure as to what. While using F8 to step through the program, it completes the Try list without hiccup but then catches the exception. How to I fix this issue?

Here's the Code:

```
Private Sub AddButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles AddUserButton.Click
    Try
        Dim SQL As String = "INSERT INTO userTable (Username, Password, LastName, FirstName, Department, " & _
            "UserPrivileges) VALUES (@Username, @Password, @LastName, @FirstName, @Department, @UserPrivileges);"
        Dim sqlCom As New OleDbCommand(SQL)

        sqlCom.Parameters.Add("@Username", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = UsernameTextbox.Text
        If PasswordTextbox.Text = ConfirmPasswordTextbox.Text Then 'Check if the passwords match
            sqlCom.Parameters.Add("@Password", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = PasswordTextbox.Text
        End If
        sqlCom.Parameters.Add("@LastName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = LastNameTextbox.Text
        sqlCom.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = FirstNameTextbox.Text
        sqlCom.Parameters.Add("@Department", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = DepartmentList.Text
        sqlCom.Parameters.Add("@UserPrivileges", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = PositionList.Text
        Debug.Print(DepartmentList.Text)

        'Open Database Connection
        sqlCom.Connection = Conn
        Conn.Open()
        sqlCom.ExecuteNonQuery()
        'Dim sqlRead As OleDbDataReader = sqlCom.ExecuteReader()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("AddUserForm: Failed to connect to Database... System Error Message: " & ex.Message, "Database Connection Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

    End Try
End Sub
```

Here's the screenshot of the error and the `AddUserForm`:

[image]

Comment: Password is a reserved word.  Escape it: `[Password]` or change the name .  But you should never store passwords as plain text - hash and salt them.

Comment: The link is at the top - it is less about the question than the answer

Comment: ...and there are 10 similar Qs listed under **Related** one of them likely matches - this is a commonly asked question